# Dropdown without a specific day

Tags: php, dropdown

I have the code:

```
<label>Visiting Date :</label>
 <?php
    $date = strtotime('Today');
    $days = 7;
    $i = 1;
    echo '<select  name="visiting_date">';
       while ($i <= $days ) {
          echo '<option value="'.$date.'">'.date('l d M Y', $date). '</option>';
          $date = strtotime( date('Y-m-d', $date) . ' + 1 Days');
          $i++;
          }
    echo '</select>';
 ?>
```

It shows next seven days including today in a dropdown list.

Now I need the dropdown list without a specific day, say Sunday. That means, the dropdown list will appear without any Sunday, but total number of days in the dropdown will be 7. Means, if the dropdown starts with Friday, the last value will be Friday of next week, no Sunday will be in the dropdown.

Any suggestion....

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this?:

```
<?php
    $date = strtotime('Today');
    $days = 7;
    $i = 1;
    $html = "";
    $notDate; // date you dont want it to

    $html  = '<select  name="visiting_date">';
       while ($i <= $days ) {
          if($date != $notDate)$html  .='<option value="'.$date.'">'.date('l d M Y', $date). '</option>';
else --$i;
          $date = strtotime( date('Y-m-d', $date) . ' + 1 Days');
          $i++;
          }
    $html.= '</select>';

echo $html;
 ?
```